# Angular SignalR and Windows Authentication (NTLM)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, windows-authentication, ntlm-authentication

My question is pretty straightforward. I am using Windows Authentication in .NET Core. On the front end part of the app (Angular) I have a HTTP interceptor which sets
*widhcredentails*: **true**
to the all HTTP requests.

This interceptor does **not** work with WebSocket, so I need a solution for adding the same code from Interceptor to the SignalR service.

Here is my interceptor code:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>
{
    request = request.clone({ withCredentials: true });
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

And here is my SignalR service:

```
  this.requestConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().
        withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}/request`).
        withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 30000, 60000, null]).
        build();
    this.requestConnection.
        start().
        then(() => console.log('Connection started')).
        catch(err => console.log(`Error while starting connection: ${err}`));
```

Keep in mind that interceptor is added in providers array in the app.module component :

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: WinAuthInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }

],
```

SignalR service is injected in the root.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've realized what was the problem. Since I am using Windows Authentications, there was no need to add any kind of JWT Authorization. Also, the interceptor code I've posted above, makes no difference lol. Meaning you don't need *withCredetials: true* either in interceptor or SignalR.

Anyway, (if you are using IIS you need to configure it by following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support), locally it will work perfectly, but if you are hosting/deploying your app on the IIS you need to do this prior, otherwise your Context will be NULL) you need to set *anonymousAuthentication* property to **false** in *launchSettings.json* (.NET Core as you backend)

```
  "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64152",
  "sslPort": 44385
}
```

Long story short, Angular code looks like this:

```
  this.requestConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().
        withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}/request`).
        withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 30000, 60000, null]).
        build();
    this.requestConnection.
        start().
        then(() => console.log('Connection started')).
        catch(err => console.log(`Error while starting connection: ${err}`));
```

in .NET Core I've just override OnConnectAsync() class to fetch connections and do some logic:

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        //remove domain name
        user = user[user.IndexOf("\\")..];
        //remove speacial chars, excluding .
        user = UserProvider.RemoveSpecialCharacters(user);
        var conId = Context.ConnectionId;

        if (UserProvider.UserConnections.Any(key => key.Key == user))
        {
            UserProvider.UserConnections[user] = conId;
        }
        else
        {
            UserProvider.UserConnections.Add(user, conId);
        }


        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows-authentication) in the Microsoft documentation:

> If Windows authentication is configured in your app, SignalR can use
> that identity to secure hubs. However, to send messages to individual
> users, you need to add a custom User ID provider. The Windows
> authentication system doesn't provide the "Name Identifier" claim.
> SignalR uses the claim to determine the user name.
>
> Add a new class that implements IUserIdProvider and retrieve one of
> the claims from the user to use as the identifier. For example, to use
> the "Name" claim (which is the Windows username in the form
> [Domain][Username]), create the following class:
>
> ```
> public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
> {
>     public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
>     {
>         return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Rather than ClaimTypes.Name, you can use any value from the User (such
> as the Windows SID identifier, and so on).
>
> **Note:** The value you choose must be unique among all the users in your system. Otherwise, a message intended for one user could end up
> going to a different user.
>
> Register this component in your Startup.ConfigureServices method:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     // ... other services ...
>
>     services.AddSignalR();
>     services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
> }
> ```
>
> In the .NET Client, Windows Authentication must be enabled by setting
> the UseDefaultCredentials property:
>
> ```
> var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
>     .WithUrl("https://example.com/chathub", options =>
>     {
>         options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
>     })
>     .Build();
> ```
>
> Windows authentication is supported in Internet Explorer and Microsoft
> Edge, but not in all browsers. For example, in Chrome and Safari,
> attempting to use Windows authentication and WebSockets fails. When
> Windows authentication fails, the client attempts to fall back to
> other transports which might work.

As mentioned, it is not supported by all browsers. IMO the best way to authenticate the signal R connections is using bearer tokens.

Adding the token to the connection is as easy as:

```
this.chatHubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(this.endpointsService.chatHubConnection(), {
    accessTokenFactory: () => this.getCurrentJwtToken(),
  })
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Error)
  .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 10000])
  .build();
```